# Vagrant reboots host on server 2016

Tags: vagrant, windows-server-2016

Running Windows Server 2016, Latest virtualbox & latest vagrant.

With the vagrant file below - Every time I run 'vagrant up server', it reboots the host.

No errors are shown unfortunately. How would one go about rectifying this? Has anyone come across this or can suggest specific logs to be looking into?

https://pastebin.com/RPTtB8Vn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be because of HyperV which was installed by default. Debugged by trying to start the same instance in Virtualbox which had the same effect. Logs showed no information. When creating a new VM, noticed that it was missing the '64 Bit' option for guest OS, which from past experience is down to other Hypervisors running (in some cases).

Rather tricky to troubleshoot when no logs provided any information but at least it's resolved.